# Render issue with CSS email signature on iPhone

Tags: html, css, ios, email, html-email

I am making a new signature for my email. Here is the code:

```
    <style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap');
</style>
<table cellspacing="0" width="500" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:0 9px 0 0;vertical-align: middle;" width="100" valign="top"> <img alt="Logo" width="100" style="width:100px;moz-border-radius:15%;khtml-border-radius:15%;o-border-radius:15%;webkit-border-radius:15%;ms-border-radius:15%;border-radius:15%;" src="https://i.ibb.co/FzTmBN9/testlogo.png" /> </td>
        <td style="border-left:0px solid;vertical-align: top;border-color:#acacac;padding:0 0 0 0px;" valign="middle">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="line-height: 1.6;font-family:'Open Sans','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;font-size:12px;color: #000000;letter-spacing:.8px;">
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="font: 12px 'Open Sans','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;color:#000000;">My Name</span> <span style="font-family:'Open Sans','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;color: #000000;">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 5px 0;">
                        <div style="font-family: 'Lato','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;font-size:11px;color: #000000;letter-spacing:1.2px;">My Company</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="font-family:'Lato','Verdana','Geneva', sans-serif;color:#acacac;">line 1:&nbsp;</span> <span><a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:'Open Sans','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;color:#000000;" href="tel:+">123 456 7890</a></span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="font-family:'Lato','Verdana','Geneva', sans-serif;color:#acacac;">line 2:&nbsp;</span> <span><a style="text-decoration:none;font-family:'Open Sans','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;color:#000000;" href="tel:+">123 456 7891</a></span> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> <span style="font-family:'Lato','Verdana','Geneva', sans-serif;color:#acacac;">https://&nbsp;</span> <span style="font-family:'Open Sans','Verdana','Geneva',sans-serif;"><a href="http://website.com" style="text-decoration: none;color:#000000;" target="_blank">website.com</a></span> </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<span style="font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica','Arial', sans-serif;color:#acacac;font-size: 10px;">This communication (including any attachments) is intended only for the recipient(s) identified in the message, and may contain information that is business proprietary/confidential, privileged, or otherwise protected by law. If you are not the intended recipient, please disregard this communication and notify the sender. Any disclosure, copying, or distribution of this message, or the taking of any action based on it, without the express permission of the originator, is strictly prohibited.</span>
```

When I send myself a test email on my iPhone XS Max running iOS 13.5.1 it works well and displays like this:

[image: Working well]

But then if I rotate the phone horizontally it then does this:

[image: Horizontally failing]

And then when I turn it back to portrait mode it does this:

[image: vertical fail]

I am pretty sure this is a bug with the iOS mail app and not my code, however I want my signature to display well on any ordination. Why is this occurring? How can I fix this? I've tried adding in some breakes (`<br>`) and padding with no luck.

Comment: You have a line height at the second table. Tried removing that?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite possible you need to put the span element within a table too. Alternatively, an easier option would be to use a paragraph tag instead of a span (make it a block element, not inline, in other words).

i.e.:

```
<p style="font-family:'Open Sans','Helvetica','Arial', sans-serif;color:#acacac;font-size: 10px;">This communication (including any attachments) is intended only for the recipient(s) identified in the message, and may contain information that is business proprietary/confidential, privileged, or otherwise protected by law. If you are not the intended recipient, please disregard this communication and notify the sender. Any disclosure, copying, or distribution of this message, or the taking of any action based on it, without the express permission of the originator, is strictly prohibited.</p>
```

Comment: Tried doing that as well, same bug. Oddly enough the only way I can see to stop this bug from occurring is remove the image.

Comment: maybe the image or the `<td>` needs an explicit height?